# Kivy Carousel- need help showing multiple images

Tags: image, kivy, carousel

Does anyone know how I can get each individual image to show up on my carousel popup? It only shows the last image in the loop.

[image]

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: You are creating a new `Carousel` for each `Image` and only using the last `Carousel` in the `Popup`. Try creating just one `Carousel` before the `for` loop.